# cant get the value of my BOOTSTRAP DATEPICKER

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, null, datepicker

how to get the value of my bootstrap date picker and store it in my database? please help me.

```
<label for="cname">Date</label>
<div class="input-append" >
                        <input name="calendar" id="datepicker1" value="" class="input-small" type="text" required>
                        <button id="datepicker1btn" class="btn btn-success" type="button"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></button>
</div>
```

and my JavaScript is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                $("#datepicker0").datepicker();

                $("#datepicker1").datepicker();
                $("#datepicker1btn").click(function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $("#datepicker1").focus();

                })

            });
```

Comment: `$('#datepicker1').val()`

Answer (score 0):

$("#datepicker0").val();

you can capture the the date by getting the value of the input b